# am unable to redirect to filtered table page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I wanted to filter my table by ticket Name. Despite the table getting filtered it is getting redirected to the unfiltered table after 10 seconds. My app.js page is coded in such a way that it should render result.js only.

```
//Function to filter the table element by ticketName
function myFunction() {
            alert("Fetching table result")
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            filter = input.value;
            table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                if (td) {
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.startsWith(filter)) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
           }
}
```

HTML:

```
    <!-- Getting ticketName wise value-->
    <form onsubmit="myFunction();return true" action="/result" method="GET">
        <div id="ticketDate">

            TICKET NAME:
            <input type="text" name="myInput" id="myInput">

            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
        </div>
    </form>`
displaying Table contents

<% for (var i = 0; i < ticketNameArr.length; i++) { %>

        <tr>
            <td><%=ticketNameArr[i].TicketName%> </td>


            <td><%=ticketNameArr[i].InputLocationMessage%></td>
            <td><%=ticketNameArr[i].ResultLocationMessage%></td>
            <td><%=ticketNameArr[i].FTPSTATUS%> </td>
            <td><%=ticketNameArr[i].TicketStatusInput%></td>
            <td> <%=ticketNameArr[i].TicketStatusResult%> </td>
            <td> <%=ticketNameArr[i].LogStatus%> </td>
            <td> <%=ticketNameArr[i].ReportStatus%> </td>
            <td><%=ticketNameArr[i].InputTime%></td>
            <td><%=ticketNameArr[i]. InputModifiedTime%></td>
            <td><%=ticketNameArr[i].OutputTime%></td>
            <td><%=ticketNameArr[i]. OutputModifiedTime%></td>
            <td><%=ticketNameArr[i].LogCreateTime%></td>
            <td><%=ticketNameArr[i]. LogModifiedTime%></td>
            <td><%=ticketNameArr[i]. FtpTime%></td>
        </tr>

        <% } %>
```

Comment: Change `return true` in onsubmit to `return false` to prevent the redirect.